# Is there a way to avoid size limit when using getResources().openRawResource()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load an XML file from res/raw folder in my Android project when the app first runs. I do this with this line:

```
InputStream xmlStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xmlfile);
```

I then want to use a SAX Parser to get data from the XML file. When doing this LogCat shows the following error:

```
Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (1290892 vs 1048576)
```

Is there anyway around this 1MB limit?

After a few Google searches, I found people who have split their files into 1MB chunks, but these weren't XML files so I am not sure how I would rejoin them before making the InputSource for my SAX Parser.

My file is not created by me, so I can't really edit it (although I may have to) and my code works if I retrieve it from Internet. Its around 1,300KB in size, so I want to not have to download it each time app run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anyway around this 1MB limit?

Give your file an extension that will not be compressed by `aapt` during the build process. For example, I think it skips compressing `.mp3` files.

Comment: +1 That worked a treat! Thanks very much. Will tick this question answered later, just waiting for any other solutions!

Comment: Hello sir, I also faced the same problem. I tried your solution and It works. But .mp3 extension seems inappropriate for a database file. Now I want to know, which file types are not compressed in Android? (Other proper extension than mp3, I can use for my database file).