# How can I split my db into 1 mb pieces?

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, terminal, split

I have a sqlite db named sports.db that is 9.8 mb in size. I would like to split it up in Terminal into 1mb pieces (I hate you Android), what is the terminal command syntax that will do that for me?

split 1 sports.db didn't do it for me...

EDIT:

It is possible to cut a file up into raw binary pieces in DOS, or the mac equivalent Terminal. That's all I want to do. I just can't figure out the syntax.

Thanks

LATE UPDATE:

This is what worked for what I wanted -

split -b 1m input prefix

where input and prefix are your input file and what you want the prefix of your output files to be

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to do this, but I imagine it could be because of the 1mb limit on resource sizes imposed by android.  If so, another way people seem to get around it is by giving the db a different name (of a type not compressed by aapt), such as sports.mp3, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976554/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-size-limit-when-using-getresources-openrawresource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what u want to do. But if u want to copy database into sd-card or internal storage from assets, I have some solution u might need.
Split the database into 1MB using hj-split and Copy using InputStream. Here is some code for u

```
    InputStream databaseInput = null;
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;\\here is u'r db name and path
    OutputStream databaseOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        databaseInput = myContext.getAssets().open("sport.db.00"+i);\\
        while ((length = databaseInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            databaseOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            databaseOutput.flush();
        }
        databaseInput.close();
    }
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for the ambiguity, see my update above for more info